# How to force javascript to run after the required validation control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox that should not be empty, so I have placed a **required validation control** next to it. I have also a **javascript confirmation box** that asks the user is he's sure to submit the information.

The problem is that the Confirmation is appearing first, then the validation is kicking in after. I'd like to inverse that. I want the validation to proceed first. If there is no more error, then the user is asked if he's sure to submit the info.

## EDIT

This the markup

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="_lnkAddUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" OnClientClick = "return ConfirmAddEdit(this.id)"
     CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:TextBox ID="_tbLocationName" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("LocationName") %>'/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqLocationName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Location name cannot be empty string." Text = "*" ControlToValidate = "_tbLocationName" />
```

This is the javascript

```
function ConfirmActive(id) {
    var action = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to " + action + " this location?");
    if (r == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The more code you share with us the easier it is to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is, but I'd guess you're having one of two problems.

The first thing to check is that your validation code is before your confirmation code

```
validate();
confirm();
```

Easy enough. The second and I'm guess your actual problem is that you're using remote validation, so instead of the above solution what you'd want is to make your confirmation code be a callback to your validation code. How you do that depends on how you're setting up the validation request. Post that code and we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The way I normally do it is to have the following javascript...

```
var cont = true;
if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) === "function") {
  cont = Page_ClientValidate();
}
if (cont) {
  cont = window.confirm("are you sure?");
}
return cont;
```

This will check to see if the ASP.NET function is available, and if so run it... if it's valid then the confirm is fired.  The final result is sent back to the click handler as to whether to continue or not.

---

**Update**

To give a bit more explanation:

When you set the `OnClientClick` attribute, the javascript you set is always run first... therefore if you have any `validator` controls in your page, they will only be run **after** your javascript.  This is obviously not what you want.

What my solution does is to call the exact same function that would be called by the browser after your javascript, but **before**.  The minor downside is that the validation will be carried out twice (one directly by you, and then again after your function has run).

```
function ConfirmActive(id) {
  var cont = true;
  if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) === "function") {
    cont = Page_ClientValidate();
  }
  if (cont) {
    var action = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    cont = confirm("Are you sure you want to " + action + " this location?");
  }
  return cont
}
```

Comment: My question is to know if I need to put this inside a javascript function. As you can see, the validation is not done by a function I wrote but rather by the require validation control.

Comment: @Richard, yes you would put it within a function. Therefore, instead of calling the `window.confirm` within the `onclick`, you would call a function.  I will update my answer with a fuller explaination